# How to use Format keyword in json schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Hi I am learning JSON schema,
 I am having a doubt regarding format keyword by this
    http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.7.3
there are some predefined format types and we can also add some custom formats. My doubt is ***how to add those custom formats and validate it*** using any JSON schema validation tools

thanks
Lakshmanan

Answer (score 0):

The way how custom formats are added to a schema validator is always implementation-specific. So if you use a PHP validator then you have to write a PHP class / function, if you use a java validator then you implement a java class. I can just hardly imagine any ways to write an implementation-independent custom validator. A schema validator may even decide not to support custom formats (although popular implementations do).

I personally don't recommend using custom formats. They are always implememtation-dependent, so if you want to consume your schema from different languages then most probably you have to write the format validator multiple times.